# Order by for desc table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large table with around 100 columns and hence is difficult to locate a column when using `desc tablename`.

Can I do a `order by` when I describe a table e.g. `desc users order by something`?

The output of `desc users` has `Field | Type` as column headers `Field` has column names, so I would like to do something like `desc users order by Field`. Is there something for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the ANSI INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
  [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```

Reference:

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'media_items'
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME`   
Had to do `DISTINCT` as it was showing up columns twice.

Comment: @Pravin: I don't think that'd be necessary if you specify the `table_schema` -- I think you've got the table in two databases/schemas.

Comment: @^: yes, adding one more condition for `table_schema` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
order by users,something desc
```